# Не удается конвертировать String в enum

Tags: java, enum

```
public enum Colors {

    WHITE("white"), LIGHT_GRAY("lightGray"), GRAY("gray"), 
    DARK_GRAY("darkGray"), BLACK("black"), RED("red"), PINK("pink"), 
    ORANGE("orange"), YELLOW("yellow"), GREEN("green"), MAGENTA("magenta"), 
    CYAN("cyan"), BLUE("blue");

    private final String name;

    private Colors(String _name) {
        name = Colors.fromString(_name);//здесь компилятор ругается incompatible types
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static Colors fromString(String _name) {
        if (_name != null) {
            for (Colors clr : Colors.values()) {
                if (_name.equalsIgnoreCase(clr.name)) {
                    return clr;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such value");
    }

}
```

Comment: `name = Colors.fromString(_name);//здесь компилятор ругается incompatible types` - `name`- это `String`, `fromString` - возвращает `Colors`

Answer (score 5):

[Вы неправильно использовали конструктор для Enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Кроме того, обычно Enum именуется существительным в единцественном числе.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Color.fromString("black"));
    System.out.println(Color.fromString("BlaCk"));
    System.out.println(Color.fromString("qqq"));
 }

    public enum Color {
        WHITE("white"), LIGHT_GRAY("lightGray"), GRAY("gray"),
        DARK_GRAY("darkGray"), BLACK("black"), RED("red"), PINK("pink"),
        ORANGE("orange"), YELLOW("yellow"), GREEN("green"), MAGENTA("magenta"),
        CYAN("cyan"), BLUE("blue");

        private final String name;

        Color(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public static Color fromString(String name) {
            for (Color color : Color.values()) {
                if (color.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    return color;
                }
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such value '" + name + "'");
        }
    }
```

Результат:

```
BLACK
BLACK
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such value 'qqq'
```

Comment: что поменялось?

Comment: Я пытаюсь в конструкторе реализовать проверку и форматирование введенного значения. Чтобы проходило BLACK, black, BLacK и т.д.

Comment: @SagamorNord стоит заменить только  if (color.name.equals(name))  на equalsIgnoreCase и будут проходить все значения

Comment: Спасибо, помогло в итоге.